# New tag for the "Bayes theorem"

Tags: discussion, tags

Shall we create a separate tag for the "Bayes theorem"?

It is one of the crucial cornerstones of bayesian statistics and statistics overall. I find 1095 questions treating this topic.

Comment: Why a separate tag from [tag:bayesian]?

Comment: I always perceived the tag "bayesian" as a rather generic tag for distinguishing between bayesian and frequentist statistics.